# Get list of "share via" apps

Tags: android, android-intent

Some apps have its custom share list instead of Android default.It's something like this:
[image: Share via custom list]
How to retrieve apps with `send` intentfilter?

**EDIT:** There's not some intent method that retrieves app list.

Comment: and what are your doubt?

Comment: It depends on the intent... But this isn't asking a question

Comment: Apps, like youtube, picsart, don't use the classic chooser, these apps retrieve other ones with SEND filter and put it on a listview or gridview.

Comment: My problem is, how to retrieve these apps

Comment: @zgc7009 i edited the question and make it a question

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html and there are tons of intents http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to get this list of activities.

> Retrieve all activities that can be performed for the given intent.

For sharing plain text just do something like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
          .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject of share")
          .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some text here")
          .setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> shareWith = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

For other data types you only need to adapt your intent of [`ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of activities that can resolve a specific intent using the code snippet below.

You can assume that if `itemsThatCanResolveYourIntent.size == 0` that the intent cannot be handled by anything natively.

```
Intent yourIntent = new Intent(...);
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> itemsThatCanResolveYourIntent = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(yourIntent, 0);
```